# Hosting an MVC3 application on Mono

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mono

I'm able to host a small MVC3 application on Mono, but when trying to host my real site, I get some exceptions.

Versions:

- Mono 2.10.6
- C#4
- MVC3 using Razor
- NHibernate 3.1.0.4
- FluentNHibernate 1.2.0.712
- MySql.Data 6.4.4.0
- MvcContrib 3.0.51.0

Here I'm trying to run `xsp4` on my Windows box, but I get the same error on Linux.

I don't get any additional information using `--verbose`. Does anybody know why this error occur, or how I can get some additional information on the error?

```
Handling exception type TargetInvocationException
Message is Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
IsTerminating is set to True
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Server stack trace:
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectRecord.LoadData (System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager manager, ISurrogateSelector selector, StreamingContext context) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups () [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.ReadNextObject
(System.IO.BinaryReader reader) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.ReadObjectGraph (BinaryElement elem, System.IO.BinaryReader reader, Boolean readHeaders, System.Object& result, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Header[]& headers) [0x00000]
in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.NoCheckDeserialize (System.IO.Stream serializationStream, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.HeaderHandler handler) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize
(System.IO.Stream serializationStream) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.DeserializeCallData (System.Byte[] array) [0x00000] in :0
  at (wrapper xdomain-dispatch) System.AppDomain:DoCallBack (object,byte[]&,byte[]&)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
 ---> System.ArgumentException: Couldn't bind to method 'SetHostingEnvironment'.
  at System.Delegate.GetCandidateMethod (System.Type type, System.Type target, System.String method, BindingFlags bflags, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnBindFailure) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Type target, System.String method, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnBindFailure) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Type target, System.String method) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.DelegateSerializationHolder+DelegateEntry.DeserializeDelegate (System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.DelegateSerializationHolder..ctor (System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctx) [0x00000] in :0
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in :0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at (wrapper xdomain-invoke) System.AppDomain:DoCallBack (System.CrossAppDomainDelegate)
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:DoCallBack (System.CrossAppDomainDelegate)
  at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost (System.Type hostType, System.String virtualDir, System.String physicalDir) [0x00000] in :0
  at Mono.WebServer.VPathToHost.CreateHost (Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer server, Mono.WebServer.WebSource webSource) [0x00000] in :0
  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.RealMain (System.String[] args, Boolean root, IApplicationHost ext_apphost, Boolean quiet) [0x00000] in :0
  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Server stack trace:
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectRecord.LoadData (System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager manager, ISurrogateSelector selector, StreamingContext context) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups () [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.ReadNextObject
(System.IO.BinaryReader reader) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.ReadObjectGraph (BinaryElement elem, System.IO.BinaryReader reader, Boolean readHeaders, System.Object& result, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Header[]& headers) [0x00000]
in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.NoCheckDeserialize (System.IO.Stream serializationStream, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.HeaderHandler handler) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize
(System.IO.Stream serializationStream) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.DeserializeCallData (System.Byte[] array) [0x00000] in :0
  at (wrapper xdomain-dispatch) System.AppDomain:DoCallBack (object,byte[]&,byte[]&)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
 ---> System.ArgumentException: Couldn't bind to method 'SetHostingEnvironment'.
  at System.Delegate.GetCandidateMethod (System.Type type, System.Type target, System.String method, BindingFlags bflags, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnBindFailure) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Type target, System.String method, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnBindFailure) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Type target, System.String method) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.DelegateSerializationHolder+DelegateEntry.DeserializeDelegate (System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.DelegateSerializationHolder..ctor (System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctx) [0x00000] in :0
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in :0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at (wrapper xdomain-invoke) System.AppDomain:DoCallBack (System.CrossAppDomainDelegate)
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:DoCallBack (System.CrossAppDomainDelegate)
  at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost (System.Type hostType, System.String virtualDir, System.String physicalDir) [0x00000] in :0
  at Mono.WebServer.VPathToHost.CreateHost (Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer server, Mono.WebServer.WebSource webSource) [0x00000] in :0
  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.RealMain (System.String[] args, Boolean root, IApplicationHost ext_apphost, Boolean quiet) [0x00000] in :0
  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0
```

Comment: Parallel mono installation/GAC problem maybe? Look at this thread: http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-list/2009-December/044136.html Otherwise post a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the reason. I had several System.Web.* dll's in by bin folder. Removing these fixes the problem.

Comment: Do you mean that you had duplicates, or you just removed all system.web.* files from your bin?

Comment: @Chazt3n: Don't remember. This is over a year old :)

Comment: Ok no problem, I'm getting the same error and I can't for the life of me understand why yet :/

Comment: I had the same issue when I copied System.Web.dll to bin folder. Removing it solved this error.

Comment: Removing the one DLL still fixes it!

Answer (score 1):

The problem persists on MVC 4/5 too. The dll is System.Web.dll. It must be deleted when publishing to mono.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Mvc project with Xamarin. The dll that you need will be in the bin folder. Will work just fine